# NHibernate many to many backward query

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

This is a question asked with an ignorance of thew subject matter, but i have searche dlong and hard so i hope this will not be too painful.

I'm using nhibernate for a many to many query.

My objects map (not my design, not getting changed any time soon):

Computer (id, name, etc...) -> (mapping table ) -> Config ( id, key, value )

One computer may have many configs, any config may belong to multiple computers. i can read a computer out fine and the list(bag) member is populated fine.

I then want to find a computer that has numerous configs.

E.g. all computers that have:
OS : Windows
CPU : 2GHz
etc.

Any assistance on how I could put this into a criteria query would be greatly appreciated. I've done some of the basics but wrapping my head around this is proving hard work.

Cheers for any assistance,
Rob.

Comment: Is it mapped as a bag or a map?

Answer (score 1):

If the parameters are always the same, use a query like the following:

```
var computers = session.CreateQuery(
    @"select c
    from Computer c
      inner join c.Configurations as osconfig
      inner join c.Configurations as cpuconfig
    where
      osconfig.Name = 'OS' 
      and osconfig.Value = :os
      and cpuconfig.Name = 'CPU' 
      and cpuconfig.Value = :cpu")
  .SetString("os", "Windows")
  .SetString("cpu", "2GHz")
  .List<Computer>();
```

If you mapped it as a map, you can even do something like this:

```
var computers = session.CreateQuery(
    @"select c
    from Computer c
    where
      c.Configurations['OS'] = :os
      and c.Configurations['CPU'] = :cpu")
  .SetString("os", "Windows")
  .SetString("cpu", "2GHz")
  .List<Computer>();
```

If the parameters are always different, use criteria to add them dynamically.